# How to keep database secure even if someone put it on another pc?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database and want to lock it ... I know I can make a user with password and give him all the permissions on this database but this solution will not work with someone take the database files and open it in another computer .... I hope I was clear
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect sensitive columns (for instance, account numbers) by encrypting them before you store them.  To protect the entire database, store the data files themselves in an encrypted filesystem and ensure they are accessible only to the server (and not to individual users).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Microsoft EFS to encrypt your data directory. Just be sure to save your backup cert to a secure location.